# Extracting subgraph in tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I have pretrained network and I'm trying to get just a part of it (subgraph) tf graph along with variables and saver object.

this is how I'm doing it:

```
subgraph = tf.graph_util.extract_sub_graph(default_graph, list of nodes to preserve)
tf.reset_default_graph()
tf.import_graph_def(subgraph)
```

This however removes all variables (when I call reset_default_graph). Even If I explicitely add the operation nodes for variables (only the "variable" type operations) into the "list of nodes to preserve".

How can I preserve subgraph of larger graph while preserving values of variables?
Is it a matter of addition some new nodes to "preserve list"?

The relation between graph nodes and variables is still unclear to me and tutorial merely mentions that creation of variable creates some operations (nodes) in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are doing looks right. As you said, a Variable is a simply an operation (a node in graph) that outputs a tensor of certain values. You should be able to add Variable nodes to the list to preserve them, as you have been already doing. Could you use print(sess.graph_def) to make sure the names you provided are correct?

Comment: Variable is a set of operations that are connected. Typically it consitst of ops: "variable[variable]", "assign[assign]", "read[identity]" (first part is a name, square brackets are for type) and whole set of ops for initializer. The problem is graph exporting cuts the variable structure in a way it isn't recognized as variable. Selecting all the required ops is cumbersome - and is not the smartest way.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. If you look at the function interface of extract_sub_graph (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/graph_util_impl.py#L110), noting that it is just simple function without any smart processing for Variables, "selecting all the required ops" might still be your best bet. The good news is that I think you can write a simple function (with graph_def as input) to automate this cumbersome process of selecting Variable-related nodes.

Comment: Ok, I was hoping I can avoid that and maybe there exist some clean and fast way to do it using existing API. Thanks.

Comment: I just came across this function convert_variables_to_constants, which might help simplify the solution: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/graph_util_impl.py#L178